# Pandas - Creating a Dataframe from a list of Dataframes based on some conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes. The list might contain 3 or more dataframes. Number of rows in each dataframe can differ from one another. The dataframes look the following.

[image]

I have to loop through the list and create a single dataframe out of these based on the following conditions.

- If both *Line* and *Point* of two dataframes match, create a new *Res* column having the value of *Res* of the second dataframe; value of *Res* of second dataframe being inserted in the same row.
- If both *Line* and *Point* of two dataframes do not match, insert a new row, with the value of *Res* of second dataframe in the new *Res* column.

For the above mentioned sample dataframes, the resultant dataframe should look like the following:

[image]

I have tried merging etc but I am not able to do this in Pandas. Please help me to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: did you try merge ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data input:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Line':[1,1,1],'Point':[2,3,4],'Res':[1,2,3]})

df2=pd.DataFrame({'Line':[1,2,3],'Point':[2,3,4],'Res':[1,2,3]})

df3=pd.DataFrame({'Line':[3,3,3],'Point':[4,3,4],'Res':[1,2,3]})
```

We using reduce merge outer

```
l=[df1,df2,df3]

import functools


functools.reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Line','Point'],how='outer'), l)
Out[228]: 
   Line  Point  Res_x  Res_y  Res
0     1      2    1.0    1.0  NaN
1     1      3    2.0    NaN  NaN
2     1      4    3.0    NaN  NaN
3     2      3    NaN    2.0  NaN
4     3      4    NaN    3.0  1.0
5     3      4    NaN    3.0  3.0
6     3      3    NaN    NaN  2.0
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ just make up some :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Using Wen's data, first perform concatenation using `pd.concat`, and then `groupby` and reshape.

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]

i = [df.rename(columns={'Res' : 'Res{}'.format(i)}) for i, df in enumerate(df_list, 1)]

df = pd.concat(df_list)\
       .groupby(['Line', 'Point'], sort=False)\
       .max()\
       .reset_index()

df

   Line  Point  Res1  Res2  Res3
0     1      2   1.0   1.0   NaN
1     1      3   2.0   NaN   NaN
2     1      4   3.0   NaN   NaN
3     2      3   NaN   2.0   NaN
4     3      4   NaN   3.0   3.0
5     3      3   NaN   NaN   2.0
```